# How do I install SQL Server 2008 Express R2 SP1 to an existing R2 Express instance?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-r2

Windows update on my Windows 7 64 bit system says I have an optional update available, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (KB2528583). When I try to install it through Windows update, it hangs. I try stopping the installation, and that hangs as well. I have to do a full restart to clear this up.

I then went to the KB doc, and it leads me to:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26729

I download SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe.

When I start it up, I'm not sure how I update my existing installation of R2? It wants to do a new installation, which looks like I would have to migrate all my DBs into the new instance it creates.

Does anyone know how I can get this installer to update my existing R2 to SP1 in place? Just update my existing instance. Should I do a repair instead?

Thanks for your help,
Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the link for the standalone service pack: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26727 (fixed)

You have the full install package above

Comment: After some confusion on my part...finally did it right. The link above worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an MSDN link that might help you to install the specific instance of SQL Server 2008 R2. I think that the Select Features should list the instances available on the machine for a given SQL version.

[**SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 - scope**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/391eba9f-4d70-45ac-820b-6c8871ffdfec/)

I installed SQL 2008 R2 Developer edition and SP1 on my machine last week and this is how the Select Features screen looks like. I am not sure if the same holds true for Express edition. SQL2008R2 is my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance name and it is selected by default.

[image: Select_Features]